# mysql 5.5 failed to “select/update…”

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2

I have 10 web window servers  ( amazon EC2) , all the server connect to 1 strong mysql windows server.

Everything works perfect, but sometimes the web servers disconnect from the mysql, and then the 10 web servers successfully to connect again but fail to "select/update..."  **the connection stuck** . ( I can see with the "SHOW PROCESSLIST" that the web servers successfully connect)

If I restart the mysql windows server I get the same problem.

**The only option to connect, is to replace the windows web servers IP addresses** .

I have the following in the config:

```
max_connect_errors = 1000000
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you specify the exact error you are getting when you try to perform SELECT/UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the `max_connections` and `max_user_connections` parameters?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections